# Obtain network IP from interface's IP and netmask

Tags: python, networking

Using python3, how is it possible to get the **network IP address** from an interface IP and netmask?

**Example:**

Having:

```
eth0 IP: 192.168.1.11  # string
netmask: 255.255.255.0    # string
```

I need to obtain:

```
network IP: 192.168.1.0 # string
```

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to apply the rules of subnet addressing?

Comment: @mkrieger1 what problem? There was no problem, I am just writing a program where I only have access to the IP address of a specific interface and the netmask used, and want to obtain the network IP. In the case of a /24 mask, that means an IP ending in 'X.Y.Z.0".

Comment: @LPython it doesn't, I don't want the IP of the interface, I already have it

Comment: But if there was no problem, why did you ask a question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I know the rules of subnet addressing, if that's what you're asking. I just don't know how to obtain, in python, a string of the network IP address from only these:

ip_eth0 = "192.168.1.11"
netmask = "255.255.255.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Python `ipaddress` module:

```
import ipaddress
net = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.11/255.255.255.0', strict=False)                                                                                                              

net.network_address                                                                                                                                                                 
# IPv4Address('192.168.1.0')
```